# Azure DataFactory Merge Filter Array output to inside ForEach Loop LookUp output values

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to merge the filter activity output which is outside of the ForEach Loop generated result. based on that, I have using item() value to filter again lookup activity output from azure database table. finally i have two kind of out with my hand. one is outside ForEach Loop acivity we have Filter activity provided one JSON array output. similarly we have inside forEach Loop activity to call lookup generated JSON array output as below like.

Filter Activity output:

```
{
    "ItemsCount": 9,
    "FilteredItemsCount": 7,
    "Value": [
        {
            "no_day": 60,
            "server": "naserxxxxx",
            "database": "db12",
            "table": "tablename12",
            "asset_id": "1cdsdsadsadsadasdsad",
            "indicator": [
                "value"
            ],
            "sub_indicator": [
                "va"
            ]
        },
        {
            "no_day": 999,
            "server": "sssss",
            "database": "db11",
            "table": "Entity",
            "asset_id": "b3ddd-b56b-4756-b5a5-ffffff",
            "indicator": [
                "val"
            ],
            "sub_indicator": [
                "ef_dt"
            ]
        },
        {
            "no_day": 30,
            "server": "sssssss",
            "database": "db15",
            "table": "tablename11",
            "asset_id": "xxx-yyyyy-ddddddddd",
            "indicator": [
                "val"
            ],
            "sub_indicator": [
                "p_dt"
            ]
        },
        {
            "no_day": 75,
            "server": "servername6",
            "database": "db10",
            "table": "tablenamet10",
            "asset_id": "d8xxx-88d3-4a38-rrr61-xxxxcec",
            "indicator": [
                "val4",
                "val3"
            ],
            "sub_indicator": [
                "time",
                "dt"
            ]
        },
        {
            "no_day": 50,
            "server": "server4",
            "database": "db4",
            "table": "tablename4",
            "asset_id": "ca31cxxxxxx-25099dddddedf",
            "indicator": [
                "valueadsad"
            ],
            "sub_indicator": [
                "val2",
                "val3"
            ]
        },
        {
            "no_day": 100,
            "server": "serverName2",
            "database": "db2",
            "table": "tablename2",
            "asset_id": "dsdssdsdsd-7a9xxxxxx",
            "indicator": [
                "val1",
                "val2"
            ],
            "sub_indicator": [
                "tx_date"
            ]
        },
        {
            "no_day": 60,
            "server": "serverName",
            "database": "dbname",
            "table": "tablename",
            "asset_id": "32232323232323323232",
            "indicator": [
                "key"
            ],
            "sub_indicator": [
                "datedt"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

LookUp acivity each iteration will generate output as below like:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "tablename",
            "path": "folder/test/<Timestamp>"
        }
    ],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzurexxIR",
                "duration": sdsds,
                "unit": "xxx"
            }
        ]
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    }
}
```

[image]

I would like to merge the Filter activity output and Lookup activity output in single manager to pass one of the notebook activity. please help us

Comment: You want merge all objects fields of lookup and filter array in each iteration and generate the array of JSON with fields like this https://i.imgur.com/DpcVPf7.png? and are the lengths of the lookup output array and Filter output array same?

Comment: yes, we expected result. please help us

Comment: our goal is needs to iterate the each object in notebook databricks to pass the value to our framework to execute the data processing.

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result, follow the below approach.

Here, I have taken your filter array of JSON in a blob file and used a lookup activity. I have given it to ForEach activity. In your case, give the Filter array to ForEach.

Inside ForEach, for this demo I have used the **same lookup activity(with same single record output) in every iteration**. In your case change the lookup query as per your requirement with `@item()` in every iteration.

These are my variables for the pipeline. `res` to store the result and `res_show` is to show the result array(optional).

[image]

Inside ForEach, take an append variable activity and give the below expression to it.

```
@json(concat('{',substring(string(item()),1,add(length(string(item())),-2)),',',substring(string(activity('My lookup').output.value[0]),1,add(length(string(activity('My lookup').output.value[0])),-2)),'}'))
```

[image]

After Foreach, I have stored the `res` array into `res_show` and this is the required array of JSON.

[image]

You can use this array of JSON as per your requirement.